# How to work with many to few mongodb relationship with feathersjs?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, feathersjs, feathers-service

I have two models, with a many-to-few relationship, that I'm modelling as follows:

```
// Portfolio
const portfoliosSchema = new Schema({
  name: { type: String, required: true },
  description: { type: String },
  user: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User', required: true },
  positions: [{
    stock: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Stock', required: true },
    cost: number,
    amount: number,
  }]
});

//  Stock
const stocksSchema = new Schema({
  exchange: { type: String, required: true },
  symbol: { type: String, required: true },
  company: { type: String },
  description: { type: String }
});
```

Without writing a custom service / in a feathers friendly way, how would I:

1. Query portfolios and populate the relevant records from the stocks
   collection
2. Simplify insert/updates to the nested positions within the portfolio schema (ie without updating the entire record)

Is this supported / should I write a custom service and/or normalize the relationship?

**Edit** - Solved #1 the first issue of getting extra data using a before hook:

```
function(hook) {
  const query = hook.params.query;
  hook.params.query = Object.assign({},query,{
    $populate: {
      path: 'positions.stock',
      select: 'exchange symbol'
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: Yes, both are supported, looking for some sample code for you.

Answer (score 0):

Sample of populate code, adjust to your needs:

```
Portfolio.find({ some: 'params' })
.populate({ path: 'stock', select: 'name -_id' })
.exec((err, portfolios) => {
  res.json({ portfolio: portfolios });
});
```

Updating a nested array item:

```
Position.update({ 'position._id': 'h43q9h94945d948jh098j6h0' }, { 
  '$set': { 'position.$.whatever': 'your-updated-stuff' }
}, err => {
  if (err) return console.log(err));
  res.json({ success: true });
});
```

Comment: Hi Alan, correct me if I'm wrong but this is  the mongoose code for how to create these queries. How would I use this with feathersjs - do I have to create a custom service with these queries?